# Printing a multi-dimensional array with additional rows and columns

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array that stores some data, and I want to print it in a matrix form (so far no prolem), thing is I want to add a few columns and rows to make it readable. Something like this:

```
3 |

2 |

1 |
   _  _  _
   1  2  3
```

(the "inside square" is my actual 2d array)

My question is, what is the best way to do this?

My current code looks like this:

```
void printBoard(char board[N][N]) {
    for (int i = N-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        printf("%d %c ", i, BAR);
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            printf("%c ", board[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    for (int l = 0; l < 2; l++) {
        for(int k = -4; k < N; k++) {
            if(k < 0) {
                printf("%c", SPACE);
            }
            else {
               if(l == 0) {
                    printf("%c ", EMDASH);
                }
                else {
                    printf("%d ", k);
                }
            }
        }
            printf("\n");
    }
}
```

It works fine but feels rather messy. Also, if I change the size of my array to be more than 10 rows/columns, the numbers don't fit right.
Is there a way to format this properly without changing the original array (the one I'm passing into the function)?

Thanks!

Comment: But then it doesn't work with double-digit numbers, it doesn't look like a straight table...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use *format specifiers* and *escape sequences* to place text where you need it to appear.  For example this code: (from a tutorial on printf and formatting)

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
    int a,b;
    float c,d;

    a = 15;
    b = a / 2;
    printf("%d\n",b);
    printf("%3d\n",b);
    printf("%03d\n",b);

    c = 15.3;
    d = c / 3;
    printf("%3.2f\n",d);
}
```

Produces this output:

```
7
   7
007
5.10
```

Of particular interest to you, as you are using integers, note the modifiers that can  be used with the "%d" specifier below in the Format specifiers section:

Escape sequences:

```
\n (newline)
\t (tab)
\v (vertical tab)
\f (new page)
\b (backspace)
\r (carriage return)
\n (newline)
```

Example Format specifiers:

```
%d (print as a decimal integer)
%6d (print as a decimal integer with a width of at least 6 wide)    
%06d (same as previous, but buffered with zeros) (added)
%f (print as a floating point)
%4f (print as a floating point with a width of at least 4 wide)
%.4f (print as a floating point with a precision of four characters after the decimal point)
%3.2f (print as a floating point at least 3 wide and a precision of 2)
```

***[There is more here](http://www.codingunit.com/printf-format-specifiers-format-conversions-and-formatted-output)***

Answer (score 2):

You can control the width of the labels (number on right side and bottom) of the graph by specifying a width specifier on the printf format strings.  That way, all the labels come out the same size.  You can also specify a string like "--------------" (make it long enough to print your longest bar) and just print out the number limited by a width specifier.

Example:

```
printf("%*s ", length, "----------------------------------------");
```

Comment: format string needs to include %s to accommodate 3rd argument in example.

Comment: Aaah, quite so.  Should have tested if first.

Comment: Almost:  for the arguments to be printed, an `int` and a `string literal`, the format specifier needs to contain both the `d` and `s` specifiers.  Something like:  `"%d %s"` will work.  Or with padding modifiers: `"%7d %s"`.

Comment: Actually, the * modifier chews up length and the s format uses the string "-----"

Comment: I just verified your `printf()` statement on my compiler.  I really did not think it would work. But you are correct, it does.  Thanks.  I learned something.  +1 for sticking with it.